# How to animate circle from the middle towards a stroke

Tags: css, css-animations

I would like to achieve the following animation with CSS:

- From the center the circle scales to 100%, so the entire circle is filled with a color
- Then again from the center the fill deformed into a stroke around the circle

I thought the best way is to use the before or after pseudo, so you can animate to circles. The problem I think I run into is that the animation on the parent is also used within the pseudo class.

If there is a better way to achieve this, I am open for suggestions :)

https://codepen.io/Caspert/pen/JjaMgKe

**HTML:**
`<div class="circle"></div>`

**SCSS:**

```
@keyframes parentFromCenter {
  0% {
    transform: scale(0);
  }
  100% {
    transform: scale(1);
  }
}

@keyframes childFromCenter {
  0% {
    transform: scale(0);
  }
  100% {
    transform: scale(1);
  }
}


.circle {
  height: 200px;
  width: 200px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  border-radius: 50vh;
  overflow: hidden;
  position: relative;
  background: black;
  animation: parentFromCenter 1s ease-in;

  &::before {
    content: "";
    height: 90%;
    width: 90%;
    position: absolute;
    top: 50%;
    left: 50%;
    transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
    background: white;
    border-radius: inherit;
    animation: childFromCenter 1s ease-in;
  }
}
```

Comment: Your pseudo animation defines the `transform` property as just the `scale()`, so it's overriding / ignoring the existing `translate()` component. If you define the `transform` in `childFromCenter` as `transform: translate(-50%, -50%) scale(..)` then it appears to do what you'd expect.

Comment: You are required to post a [mcve] here, **within your question**, and [not a link](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/254430/162698) to any other site.

Answer (score 1):

If you want the inner circle to be a cutout and see the content behind u can achieve the same effect using `box-shadow` This is the update

```
.circle2 {
 --circle-size: 200px;
 --fill-circle: calc(circle-size / 2);
 --stroke-size: 10px;
 width: var(--circle-size);
 height: var(--circle-size);
 background-color: pink;
 border-radius: 100vh;
 background: transparent;
 box-shadow: inset 0 0 0 var(--circle-size) lightblue;
 animation: parentFromCenter 1s ease-in forwards, shadow 1s 1s ease-in forwards; 
}
```

I have also updated the code pen: https://codepen.io/raul-rogojan/pen/dyqJxVB

Answer (score 1):

I'll throw in my two cents...

```css
.circle{
  width: 10px;
  aspect-ratio: 1/1;
  border-radius: 50%;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  
  animation: expanding 2s linear infinite;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  left: 100px;
  top: 100px;
  position: absolute;
}

@keyframes expanding{
  0%{
    width: 10px;
    border: 6px solid blue;
  }
  50%{
    width: 200px;
    border: 102px solid blue;
  }
  100%{
    width: 200px;
    border: 5px solid blue;
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="circle">

</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Using pseudo elements for styling seems like a good idea - but I'd go further and completely separate out the animation styling from the actual element.

This snippet keeps the element itself at its full dimensions and animates the before an after pseudo elements to grow from scale 0 to scale 1.

The before pseudo element is black and starts to grow immediately. The after pseudo element is white and waits 1 second before starting to grow.

```css
body {
  /* just for demo */
  width: 100vw;
  height: 100vh;
}

@keyframes grow {
  0% {
    transform: scale(0);
  }
  100% {
    transform: scale(1);
  }
}

.circle {
  height: 200px;
  width: 200px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  border-radius: 50vh;
  overflow: hidden;
  position: relative;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
}

.circle::before,
.circle::after {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  animation: grow 1s ease-in forwards;
  border-radius: inherit;
  transform: scale(0);
  z-index: -1;
}

.circle::before {
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  background: black;
}

.circle::after {
  height: 90%;
  width: 90%;
  top: 5%;
  left: 5%;
  background: white;
  animation-delay: 1s;
}
```

```html
<div class="circle"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to use pseudo-elements. You can just add another div inside the circle and animate each of them like so:

```
<div class="circle">
  <div class="inner"></div>
</div>
```

Also, add the `forwards` keyword to the animation so the elements keep the styling from the animation.

Here is an example: https://codepen.io/raul-rogojan/pen/dyqJxVB

Comment: For styling it is often a good idea to use just CSS, not to add another otherwise spurious element into the DOM. This is particularly the case for accessibility.